# Call the function if there is values returned by the wire method

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, wire

I have a function in LWC which is getting invoked if Wire brings some values from Apex.
but issue here i am facing is function is still getting called when data=[]

Logic :
Wire

```
@wire(getRFCt, { crid: '$crid' }) wired({ error, data }) {
        const functionName = 'wired';
        if (error) {
            //Log to print Error
        }
        else if (data) {
             {
                this.ceSler(data);
                console.log("data is here" + JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        }
    }
    
    function
    
    ceSler(data) {
        if (data !== []) {
              /// Logic for Functio
            });
        }
    }
    
    
data is here[{"T_R_R":"ASD-SDF-DFG","Id":"hgjfhgjf"}]
data is here[]
```

How to invoke the function only when (data is here[{"T_R_R":"ASD-SDF-DFG","Id":"hgjfhgjf"}]) value is present in data currently not sure why it is getting invoked for both.
kindly help me out for this.

Comment: check for length data.length > 0

Answer (score 2):

Change your condition to:

```
if(data && data.length) {
  this.ceSler(data);
}
```

0 is a "falsy" value, so if the array is empty, this condition will not call the method.

Answer (score 0):

> if(data) evaluates against null value.  In this scenario as @sfdcfox suggested you could check null and length.  Alternatively In getRFCt() method if there is no valid data make sure return null.